# NO TEMPLATE FOUND in export import wpbakery page builder plugin using thegem theme

Tags: wordpress, export, wpbakery

Saved Templates not showing up in Import & Export wpbakery page builder plugin and also i am using thegem theme.

I want export all my website pages in json formate and export from wpbakery.

plz help me how to export page in json formate.